# 0 reputation added after upvote my answer on stackoverflow, what's going wrong?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I am new to this, I also don't know how to ask question but probably I think I get my answer here, In SO I answered this question [I want to make transparent listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385264/i-want-to-make-transparent-listview-in-android/8385346#8385346) and someone upvoted it but my reputation on that is 0 instead of 10. So I can't understand what happened?

Comment: I always wondered, why do old regular users with high reputation (more than 6K for OP) use names like "user123456"?

Comment: @Idolon - post it as a question on meta...

Comment: @Idolon - That could be a feature request. After a certain amount of rep, the system would be like *Er, let's get you name there chief. There ya are. \*pat on the butt\**

Comment: @Oded Done. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114873/158912

Comment: @KublaiKhan Can you pls repost it as answer on the question I just created?

Comment: @KublaiKhan - The mortarboard badge does that.

Comment: @Oded - Even the butt pat? Impressive. Then we should expand this feature so that thereafter the system occasionally insults your poor choice of a name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have reached the reputation cap for normal votes. This is 200 per any single day.

See the [community FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/140505):

> You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately (source).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand how reputation works.