# Why do old regular users still use autogenerated names like user######?

Tags: discussion, display-names

Following my off-topic comment in [another thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114837/158912), I would like to post it as a question now:

> I always wondered, why do old regular users with high reputation use names like [user370305](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370305/user370305) ?

What's your thoughts about it? Maybe we should gently ask experienced users (after they reach some reputation value or after a certain amount of activity time) to change autogenerated names to something more meaningful?

p.s.: pls note, that I read [Why do some users have username "user########"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68053/158912). But I ask a different question here.

Comment: Maybe they like using an opaque name?  Maybe they have a looser account that doesn't require them to log in (not sure how well this would work)?

Comment: They are uncreative?  Or perhaps they want to remain incognito? I use my real name, because I never was creative enough to come up with some handle like ZOMG_ZigGY_StartDust

Comment: Until now, apparently. All hail ZOMG_ZigGY_StartDust♦!

Comment: It would be really interesting to hear the reason from one of those users.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Or they simply don't notice "edit" link on the profile page? ;)

Comment: Just to clarify: That user is actually `user370305`.  If it was really `user123456`, I think the reason for keeping the name should be obvious!  BTW, we're only a couple hundred thousand away from `user1234567`, and less than 20,000 away from `user1111111`!

Comment: Some of them have default avatars, too.

Comment: Some history: [until September 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65006/why-are-you-no-longer-inferring-user-names-from-openid) the OpenID user name would be used as a default. And related: [Is it bad to use your “real name” as your user name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69256/is-it-bad-to-use-your-real-name-as-your-user-name)

Comment: @KevinVermeer I was not sure whether to put a real user name in the title. Changed it now (hope user370305 won't complain).

Comment: Khm… 3 votes to close as "not constructive"… Would it be better to emphasize the constructive IMHO part of the question: `Maybe we should gently ask experienced users … to change autogenerated names to something more meaningful?`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some users wish to remain anonymous and low key. They have no qualms with the autogenerated names and see no reason to change it.

I don't see any benefit in making them change it either, since there's nothing to stop them from changing it to something just as meaningless as *aksgdashdkjgw* or *jingleballs*.

If identifiability is a concern, then surely having a constant username is better than users that change their names every so often.

One possible inconvenience I can think of that can result from *user** usernames is when then are more than one involved in a comment thread --  it makes the thread a little harder to follow, and the usernames a tad harder to target using `@user...`.  This is a rare edge case and is hardly worth fretting about.

Comment: Jingleballs?  Good to see some Christmas spirit on Meta.

Comment: The *only* possible inconvenience? What about the problem of even realizing that there are two different users in a thread when both of their usernames look nearly identical? I can't imagine trying to understand code where variables had names like `var581924`.

Comment: @Gabe - So you haven't noticed how many John and Mark we have here? The 'User' users are at least numbered!

Comment: @BoPersson: We have maybe 700 Johns, but 100k user######s!

Comment: @Gabe Actually we have about [7012 Johns](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2223/number-of-users-with-displayname-like-john) and about [134k user######s](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2224/number-of-users-with-displayname-like-user), but I think your point is still valid.

Answer (score 5):

I looked at the OP from the thread you refer to and based upon the lack of information they give on their profile they must prefer the sense of anonymity associated with the auto generated name. Personally i don't think it has any bearing on anything, their questions and answers are just as valid.